# .NET 4.5 MethodInfo serialization breaking change

Tags: .net, serialization, .net-4.5

## The problem

An object (with a private `MethodInfo` field) serialized with version 1.0 of an assembly won't be deserialized with the version 1.1 of that assembly (a `SerializationException` will be thrown because required method has not been found).

### What's changed?

I found that in .NET 4.5 the serialization mechanism of a `MemberInfo` via `MemberInfoSerializationHolder` has been changed. In the past (up to .NET 4.0) the serialized data was the method signature (obtained with a simple `MethodInfo.ToString()`).
According to comments in the .NET source code they added a second signature obtained via `SerializationToString()` because:

> m_signature stores the ToString() representation of the member which is sometimes ambiguous. Mulitple overloads of the same methods or properties can identical ToString(). m_signature2 stores the SerializationToString() representation which should be unique for each member. It is only written and used by post 4.0 CLR versions.

For what I can see the `MemberInfoSerializationHolder.GetRealObject()` uses this (simplified) code to resolve the method (from .NET source code):

```
for (int i = 0; i < methods.Length; i++)
{ 
    if (m_signature2 != null) // SerializationToString() signature
    {
        if (((RuntimeMethodInfo)methods[i]).SerializationToString().Equals(m_signature2))
        { 
            methodInfo = methods[i];
            break; 
        } 
    }
    else 
    {
        if (methods[i].ToString().Equals(m_signature))
        { 
            methodInfo = methods[i];
            break; 
        }
    }
}

if (methodInfo == null)
    throw new SerializationException(...);
```

In this case the deserialization fails because the `m_signature2` signature can't be found because assembly name contains version information then `String.Equals()` won't match `MyAssembly, Version=1.0.0.0` with `MyAssembly, Version=1.1.0.0` and an exception will be thrown.

## The question

I would expect the Framework will fail back to *old* search method if the *new* search fails (at least because of compatibility with existing code). I don't understand why this comparison is made with a `String.Equals()`, after all the version of an assembly is resolved at run-time (and newer version will be loaded by default), I agree it can't resolve the assembly version there but it may remove/ignore it if the *strict* search fails.

I know it's terrible to serialize a `MethodInfo` but at this moment this fix may involve too many changes (both in architecture and code) and no one would start this refactoring in that old code (moreover binary compatibility for archives must be kept for both old and new versions, in both directions).

So far I didn't try but is this issue applicable to delegates too?
Is there any solution (with attributes or with small code changes) to workaround this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I've not been able to completely solve this issue by myself. I tried to implement `ISerializable` using a *custom* implementation of `MemberInfoSerializationHolder` to mimic the old behavior (just pasted code from 4.0 version). It works fine for *new* archives but it won't work with old (deployed) applications for this scenario.
I didn't find any way to solve this issue because already shipped applications won't work (unless a patch is applied but this was not viable).

I saw implementation changed little bit over in newer builds anyway issue is preset only if there is more than one method with same name (signature is then used) otherwise just the first (and only) one is picked without any extra check.

Answer (score 2):

The best way I can think of is to implement `ISerializable` ( [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.iserializable.aspx) )

Implementing this interface on the objects with `MethodInfo` properties gives you pretty much complete control of serialization / deserialization.

The downside is that you will also have to handle all the other properties in some generic manner. Should be do-able, though.

Comment: I agree it may be solved somehow implementing ISerializable but we must preserve compatibility with existing application so I can't change what it's serialized (object serialized with the new version must be open with an older version too).

Comment: @Adriano If you implement `ISerializable` you are in control of serialization too, so you can serialize the object in a way that the old version can deserialize.

Comment: @svick I don't get the point! :) If I implement ISerializable I may serialize "my own version" of MemberInfoSerializationHolder (let's say MyMemberInfoSerializationHolder, I suppose just the old implementation of .NET 4) but then older versions (that don't implement ISerializable) won't be able to deserialize it.

Comment: @Adriano But you can choose how exactly do you implement `ISerializable`, so you can do it exactly the way .Net 4.0 does it. If you manage to do that, the two versions will be compatible.

Comment: @svick I still don't get it. I serialize the class in the same way it was serialized and for that field I serialize the "new" serialization holder (that mimics the old one). It'll work great for new version(s) but the old one will try to deserialize MyMethodInfoSerializationHolder and it won't be there...or not?