# TargetInvocationException on BinaryFormatter.Deserialize after i added strong naming to my assembly

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, strongname

I wrotea DLL with a `Save()` and a `Load()` method using `BinaryFormatter.Serialize()` and `BinaryFormatter.Deserialize()` to save or load a `List<MyObject>` to a file on my computer.

This has worked fine until i decided to add strong naming to my assembly. As soon as i add a key with a strong name to the compile process my program is no longer able to load a pre-strong-naming file. I get a `TargetInvocationException` with a `FileLoadException` as the `InnerException` saying that `MyAssembly, Version=1.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null` is not found.

When i open the file with a HEX editor i can see several references to my assembly in the the file: `MyAssembly, Version=1.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null`.

When i save a file with my new strong named assembly one thing changes: `PublicKeyToken=123456789`. Where, of course, 123456789 is another value.

Now several questions came to my mind:

1. Why is it important with which Assemblyversion the file was saved?
2. If i want to write another program that can access the data in these files... is that even possible?
3. Can i convert the pre-strong-naming-files so that i can read them with the strong named assembly?

I already tried changing `PublicKeyToken=null` into `PublicKeyToken=123456789` but that just throws a `SerializationException` saying that there is no valid `BinaryHeader` or that the object version has changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strong named assemblies are **different** assemblies (as assemblies with  a different public key are effectively different assemblies).

Given this they it's more reasonable you can't load them *instead* of expected ones because `BinaryFormatter` will try by default to load exactly required assembly.

What you can do is to create your `SerializationBinder` where you replace null `PublicKey` with `PublicKey` from current executing assembly. Your custom serialization binder can be used assigning `BinaryFormatter.Binder` property.

```
var formatter = new BinaryFormatter { Binder = new MyCustomBinder() };
```

Where `MyCustomBinder` is (just relevant parts):

```
sealed class MyCustomBinder : SerializationBinder
{
   public override Type BindToType(string assemblyName, string typeName)
   {
       var name = new AssemblyName(assemblyName);
       if (name.GetPublicKeyToken() == null) // Better check here...
       {
           var publicKeyToken = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
               .GetName().GetPublicKeyToken();

           name.SetPublicKeyToken(publicKeyToken);
       }

       // Now let's create required type using name and typeName
   }

   // Other code
}
```

Of course you should do it only for your own assemblies (not any other type you don't know about) and you should carefully check this won't break your application security.

Edit: be aware that some types use a serialization surrogate (for example `MemberInfo` through `MemberInfoSerializationHolder`). Types loaded because of this surrogate will not go through your custom serialization binder. Notable case is for delegates. Yes, it's not such great idea to serialize delegates and I'd tend to avoid it (see also [.NET 4.5 MethodInfo serialization breaking change](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14198668/1207195)) but if you have to live with it you also need to handle `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve` event (with same logic as above): attach an handler before deserialization and remove it when you're done; ideally you may do everything inside your serialization binder:

```
sealed class MyCustomBinder : SerializationBinder, IDisposable
{
    public MyCustomBinder()
    {
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += OnAssemblyResolve;
    }

    void IDisposable.Dispose()
    {
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve -= OnAssemblyResolve;
    }

    // Your code here
}
```

Used like:

```
using (var binder = new MyCustomBinder())
{
    var formatter = new BinaryFormatter { Binder = new MyCustomBinder() };
}
```

Note: I didn't try but if you need to use `AppDomain.AssemblyResolve` then you *maybe* don't even need a custom binder and everything can be done there...

Comment: Full type name (with assembly) that can be used with `Type.GetType()`. For example: `return Type.GetType(String.Format("{0}, {1}", typeName, name.ToString()));`

Comment: Ah. Now i get it. Thank you. Unfortunately it does not work. On first call of `BindToType` `assemblyName` is `mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089` and `typeName` is ``System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[MyClass, MyNamespace, Version=2.0.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]`` -> nothing happens. i still get the error.

Comment: Last paragraph: _"Of course you should do it only for your own assemblies...". That code makes sense only for your own assembly!

Comment: So since i serialize a `List<MyObject>` instead of just `MyObject` this approach won't work for me right?

Comment: It works also for you but you have to handle that. Search for _MyAssembly, Version=..._ and replace it with what AssemblyName you built.

Comment: I tried replacing the `PublicKeyToken=null` with `PublicKeyToken=<<KEY>>` (where <<KEY>> is the key that is saved in the binary file) in the strings `assemblyName` and `typeName` but that won't help either. it gives me several calls to `BindToType` but at some point there is a call where both strings are not about `MyClass` at all and after that call i get the same `Exception`. One parameter againg `mscorlib` and the other one something like `MemberInfoSerializationHolder`. I really have no clue what to do here...

Comment: You shouldn't replace blindly PublicKeyToken=null, check also assembly name. Just log each call input and output and you will see the problem...

Comment: I did log the input and the output. I did not replace `PublicKeyToken=null` on just any string but only on strings related to my Assembly. I did not see any problem but the exception i got.

Comment: You can see the output [here](https://gist.github.com/sebingel/56f224ebf843af83e904). After the last call i get the exception i described in my initial post.

Comment: It's methodholder stuff to fail. Also should do the same in AppDomain.AssemblyResolve

Comment: You welcome, note that if you have to _make your hands dirty_ with AssemblyResolve then (maybe!) you may even drop custom binder.

Comment: Yeah, Already have dropped it. Next step is dopping BinaryFormatter ;)